# SSO using Azure B2C with multiple custom policies with different domains

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, subdomain, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have been several weeks on this now. I need to achieve the next scenario with Azure AD B2C custom subdomains: for example, having `ssositeA.mydomain.com` with custom policy `b2c_1a_signin_siteA` and `ssositeB.mydomain.com` with custom policy `b2c_1a_signin_siteB` and when signin in SSO for `siteA` get signed in to `siteB`.

I've tested and that's not at least the default behaviour. Having a central sso works: for example, `sso.mydomain/<tenant id>/b2c_1a_signin_siteA` and `sso.mydomain/<tenant id>/b2c_1a_signin_siteB`. But, it's not ideal since we would like to have a branding related name in the subdomain.

The cookies are saved with the full subdomain:

```
.ssositeA.mydomain.com
.ssositeB.mydomain.com
```

Is there a way to indicate that for ssositeA and ssositeB the cookies be saved at the domain level, so we would have

```
.mydomain.com (as cookie's Domain)
```

and we can have shared the session between the two sign in sites?

Comment: Hi @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT, the problem is precisely that I do not know how to set the cookie's values in Azure AD B2C and I need to do it at Azure AD B2C level not in the clients

Comment: I would suggest you to please refer this documentation link : -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/cookie-definitions

Comment: Also, would suggest you to please refer this link also: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/564075/how-to-mark-the-cookie-from-aad-b2c-to-be-secure.html

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can surely save the cookies at the domain level rather than issuing cookies for every subdomain for SSO even though the root domain for those subdomains is the same. According to `RFC 2109` and `RFC 6265`, **if the domain name in your cookie's domain parameter doesn't start with a period, then it will not let subdomains read that cookie and if it does start with the period, then all subdomains will have full access to that cookie's value**, i.e., a `Set-Cookie from request-host ‘subdomain.myserver.com’ for ‘Domain=.myserver.com’ would be accepted wherein the origin server's fully-qualified host name must domain-match the Domain attribute of the cookie`.

Thus, by setting the **Domain property of the cookie in the header** to the domain of the sub domain, in this way you instruct the browser to send the cookie to all sub domains as below: -

```
Response.Cookies(“UID”)=1

Response.Cookies(“UID”).Domain = “.myserver.com” ‘
```

Also, you can set the ‘Domain’ attribute present in the header as below: -

```
 Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=.mydomain.com
```

Note: - `The domain attribute must domain-match the request URL for it to be valid`, which basically means it must be the **request domain** or a **super-domain**. So, this applies for both examples in the question, as well as sharing between two separate subdomains.

For more information regarding this, kindly refer to the links below: -

[Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

Comment: I think that the question is about how to achieve this at Azure B2C level (on the identity provider) not from a client perspective. If I understand correctly @ginrod wants to configure Azure B2C so it can share cookies between two B2C's custom policies.

Comment: yes @kartikbhiwapurkar-mt, what yosbel said is exactly what I need to achieve if possible

Comment: @ginrod Did you manage to get this working?